# Android - Scrollview not scrolling in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, scrollview

I have a fragment that containing a scrollview, but won't scroll the views if `layout_height="match_parent"`. if i set `layout_height="300dp"`, scrollview is scrolls the views

when i use an activity that containing scrollview, it scroll the views even if `layout_height="match_parent"`. hope that i can find the correct answer to solve my problem.
i've tried to looking for same answer, but still won't scroll the view.

sorry for my english

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/beranda_rootView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Saldo sampai hari ini, 21 Juli 2017"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_muted"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="asdasdasdasd"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <!--<ListView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/lv_beranda_tabungan_list"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
                    <!--</ListView>-->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:text="Saldo"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.8"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:text="Rp. 00.000.00"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Transaksi bulan ini"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_muted"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_title_total_pemasukkan_bulan_ini"
                            android:text="Total pemasukkan"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_value_total_pemasukkan_bulan_ini"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_title_total_pemasukkan_bulan_ini"
                            android:text="Rp. 00.000.000"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"

                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_title_total_pengeluaran_bulan_ini"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_total_pemasukkan_bulan_ini"
                            android:text="Total pengeluaran"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_value_total_pengeluaran_bulan_ini"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_title_total_pengeluaran_bulan_ini"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_value_total_pemasukkan_bulan_ini"
                            android:text="Rp. 00.000.000"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"

                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Transaksi bulan lalu"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_muted"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_title_total_pemasukkan_bulan_lalu"
                            android:text="Total pemasukkan"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_value_total_pemasukkan_bulan_lalu"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_title_total_pemasukkan_bulan_lalu"
                            android:text="Rp. 00.000.000"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"

                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_title_total_pengeluaran_bulan_lalu"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_total_pemasukkan_bulan_lalu"
                            android:text="Total pengeluaran"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_value_total_pengeluaran_bulan_lalu"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_title_total_pengeluaran_bulan_lalu"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_value_total_pemasukkan_bulan_lalu"
                            android:text="Rp. 00.000.000"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color_strong"

                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Pemasukkan berdasarkan kategori"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_muted"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="asdasdasdasd"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <!--<ListView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/lv_beranda_kategori_pemasukkan_list"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
                    <!--</ListView>-->
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Pengeluaran berdasarkan kategori"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_muted"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="asdasdasdasd"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <!--<ListView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/lv_beranda_kategori_pengeluaran_list"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
                    <!--</ListView>-->
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My fragment.java:

```
public class BerandaFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beranda, null, true);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your layout's root container in parent activity?

Comment: i'm using **android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout** for root layout,,

this layout is basic application for navigation draw in android studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to inflate a fragment on activity which contains the scroll view means (activity and fragment both contains a scroll view) then you  should use nested scroll view in activity XML...just replace the scroll view with nested scrollview in activity

Comment: no you have to use the nested scroll view as a parent and scroll view as child because nested scroll view is used to contain multiple scroll view(scroll view in scroll view)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the layout height for your scroll view as `wrap_content`.

Comment: i 've tried like that but still won't scroll,,, if i put scrollview inside of tabLayout / pageViewer, it's scroll

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the app screen!

Comment: check this too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use layout height as `wrap_content` and use `layout_weight` as 1 in ScrollView xml.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i've tried and still won't scroll the views,,,